# como repito un comando en cmd para cada archivo que tenga en una carpeta

Tags: cmd

Tengo una carpeta con muchos archivos .iso ( d:\isos).
Quiero comprimirlos con gzip y necesito crear un loop que por cada .iso que este en esa carpeta ejecute gzip.exe archivox.iso y asi hasta que comprima todos los archivos de la carpeta.

Espero haber sido mas claro con la pregunta.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%f in (C:\path\to\files\*.txt) do (
    :: El comando que quieras realizar sobre los ficheros. %%f sera el fichero.
)
```

Sobre esto que te pego, debes modificar la ruta y además el formato según lo que estés trabajando.

Saludos,

Comment: for %%f in (g:\1\*.iso) do (
    z:\gzip\bin\gzip.exe -9 -k %%f 
)                 esto es lo que he puesto en un .bat pero se cierra nada mas abrirse. las rutas estan bien. que falla ?